# How to call a socket to connect inside a function?

Tags: python, sockets

See the example below, in this case everything is running good and the connection is stable.

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket
from ScrolledText import *
import threading
import time
port = 6669
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.31.158", port))
s.send("User")
print "Connection Created"
```

But in this case connection with server is breaking while I am trying to call it using a function.

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket
from ScrolledText import *
import threading
import time
def myFunction():
        port = 6669
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(("192.168.31.158", port))
        s.send("Suparno")
        print "Connection Created"
myFunction()
```

Is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to return the socket from the function so you can use it after the function returns.

Comment: If you don't return it, then the connection is closed when the variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to solve this problem. Thanks Mr Barmar.

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket
from ScrolledText import *
import threading
import time
def myFunction():
        global s
        port = 5500
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(("192.168.31.158", port))
        s.send("User")
        print "Connection Created"
        return s
myFunction()
```